# Possible to retrieve file from Docker image that is not a container?

Tags: docker

I have created an application that uses docker. I have built an image like so: `docker build -t myapp .`

While in my image (using `docker run -it myapp /bin/bash` to access), a image file is created.

I would like to obtain that file to view on my local as I have found out that viewing images on Docker is a complex procedure.

I tried the following: `docker cp myapp:/result.png ./` based on suggestions seen on the webs, but I get the following error: `Error response from daemon: No such container: myapp`

Comment: You need to do the cp while the container is running - i.e. when you can be in your image - do it from outside of the running container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Image name != container name

`myapp` is the name of the *image*, which is not a running container.

When you use `docker run`, you are creating a container which is based on the `myapp` image. It will be assigned an ID, which you can see with `docker ps`. Example:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
aa58c8ff2f34        portainer/portainer   "/portainer"        4 months ago        Up 5 days           0.0.0.0:9909->9000/tcp   portainer_portainer_1
```

Here you can see a container based on the `portainer/portainer` image. It has the ID `aa58c8ff2f34`.

Once you have the ID of your container, you can pass it to `docker cp` to copy your file.

### Specifying the container name

Another approach, which may be preferable if you are automating / scripting something, is to specify the name of the container instead of having to look it up.

```
docker run -it --name mycontainer myapp /bin/bash
```

This will create a container named `mycontainer`. You can then supply that name to `docker cp` or other commands. Note that your container still has an ID like in the above example, but you can also use this name to refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could map a local folder to a volume in the image, and then copy the file out of the image that way.

```
docker run -it -v /place/to/save/file:/store myapp /bin/bash cp /result.png /store/
```